# При выполнении тестов возникает org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException "Таблица не найдена"

Tags: sql, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Имеется Spring Boot приложение, работающее с базой данных, в данном случае h2. При выполнении тестов на проверку работоспособности методов взаимодействия с базой данных, появляется исключение:

---

**Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Таблица "OFFICE" не найдена
Table "OFFICE" not found; SQL statement:
insert into office (office_id, office_address, office_is_active, office_name, office_org_id, o_id, office_phone, version) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-193]**

---

В чем может быть проблема? Полный код лежит на гите: https://github.com/kaldihin/Bell_Integrator_Task.git

---

Приветствуются любые варианты догадок и ответов, а также обоснованная критика :)

Answer (score 1):

Таблица не найдена, потому что у вас в настройках Hibernate указано, что схема не нуждается в создании/обновлении.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Это может быть причиной по которой тесты не проходят. Поменяйте настройки так, чтобы автоматически создавалась схема, используя следующую конфигурацию

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: Когда установлено значение "none", по умолчанию должны ведь создаваться таблицы из schema.sql и data.sql из каталога resource?

Comment: С чего вдруг такое могло взяться?